# Pages are Missing when Scrolling Horizontally

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am working on the horizontal scroll. Why is it that after I placed the transformation objects in my page only one appears?

I've checked to see if I made any errors. Im only using textEdit so I could be overlooking something.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-organ: top left;
}

.one {
  background: white;
}

.two {
  background: grey;
}

.three {
  background: black;
}

.four {
  background: green;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-organ: top left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slide one"></div>
    <div class="slide two"></div>
    <div class="slide three"></div>
    <div class="slide four"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expecting scroll to go 4 pages white grey black and green

Comment: `transform-organ`? o_O

Comment: overflow-x: hidden; Isn't this your scroll?

Comment: @j08691 I updated that to origin

Comment: @jmag yea its my scroll the template I followed said to hid it. I updated the code tho only problem is theres to much padding around the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had some errors. Was using TextEdit so I couldnt catch it with my eye. the problem is there is still some white space on the side Im gonna have to work on some padding. html is fine
Css

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.slide {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
   }
.one {
background: white;
}
.two {
background: grey;
}
.three {
background: black;
}
.four {
background: green;
}
.outer-wrapper {
 width: 100vh;
 height: 100vw;
 transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 scrollbar-width: none;
 -ms-overflow-style:none;
}
::webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;}
```